# Using the definition show, that $\displaystyle \lim_{\substack{x \rightarrow 1 \\ y \rightarrow 2}} (x^2+3y^2)=13$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, multivariable-calculus

$\displaystyle \lim_{\substack{x \rightarrow 1 \\ y \rightarrow 2}} (x^2+3y^2)=13$ it's pretty simple to see, that the limit of it is 13, but how can I show it using the definition? Do I have to show the continuity of the function at this point?

Comment: What does your definition say about limits? If you write it for this particular case, where do you get stuck?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $x^2+3y^2 - 13 = (x-1)(x+1)+3 (y-2)(y+2)$.

Comment: $x^2+3y^2=13$ is an ellipipse, can I maybe use this fact?

Comment: No. You are trying to show that if $(x,y)$ is close enough to $(1,2)$ then the above quantity will be small.